# Salesforce integrate with SAP Server using External DataSource

Tags: webservices, integration, customization

I am trying to integrate with SAP Server using External DataSource feature in salesforce but i am getting the exception once i click the validate and Sync button.

Exception: he external server is unreachable. Make sure that the Server URL is correct and that the server's SSL certificate is valid and correct for its domain name.

Can any one kindly help on this?

Thanks,
Venkatsforce

Comment: Have you done the things that support have suggested? What exactly are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @AlexTennant  Can you kindly explain how can i approach this "The Salesforce's IP addresses should be whitelisted at the Firewall/company's Network or where you are trying to make the callout to allow connections from Salesforce". Can I add the Salesforce IP Addresses in NetworkAccess under SecurityControls in Salesforce?

Comment: You need to white list the salesforce ip range on your network or where ever your SAP is hosted.  You're asking a combination of things which may not even be related to salesforce. Could you try to update/edit your question to only contain a single question ? If needed you can ask multiple questions, if they are related to salesforce technologies. How to configure SAP is out of the scope of this site and there are probably SAP forums who can help you with that.

Comment: @Samuel De Rycke Thanks for your response. I am trying SAP Integration using external Data source in Salesforce.